# Can we use something like ampersand for animation keyframe name?

Tags: sass

For example I have a css with code

```
.className {
  animation: keyframesName 10s;
  @keyframes keyframesName {
    0% {...}
    100% {...}
  }
}
```

I'm thinking if we can do something like `&_keyframesName` to prevent duplicate keyframeName declare.

I haven't find SCSS document has something like this... anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just about having a unique name for the keyframe, then you can use the [`unique-id` function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/string#unique-id):

> ```
> string.unique-id()
> unique-id() //=> string
> ```
>
> Returns a randomly-generated unquoted string that’s guaranteed to be a valid CSS identifier and to be unique within the current Sass compilation.

Your example would look the following:

```css
@use "sass:string";

.class {
    $keyframesName: string.unique-id();
    animation: $keyframesName 10s;
    @keyframes #{$keyframesName} {
        0% {}
        100% {}
    }
}
```

Or using the *discouraged* global alias:

```css
.class {
    $keyframesName: unique-id();
    animation: $keyframesName 10s;
    @keyframes #{$keyframesName} {
        0% {}
        100% {}
    }
}
```

Example result:

```css
.class {
  animation: uw4m92d 10s;
}
@keyframes uw4m92d {}
```